# How to write an integration test for Service layer which have few dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have two classes

```
@Service
public class A {

}

@Service
public class B {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
}
```

I would like to write an integration test which will test my B class. I don't want to load entire Spring Boot application so @SpringBootTest annotation will not work for me. I have tried to use @WebMvcTest annotation but it is loading other classes as well.

Is there a way to load only certain classes or packages?

Comment: Opinion: There is little value added in testing several but not all of your application components at once. Perform extensive unit testing, and then test your business requirements on the full application stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know how to do this with TestNG
Your test class should extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. Now you can also add `Bean` and configurations so that you can mock your `@Autowired` objects, if needed it should be something similar to the one below.

Example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTest.TestConfig.class})
class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    private A mockA = mock(A.class);

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public A a() {
            return mockA;
        }

        @Bean
        public B b() {
            return new B();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer partially.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {A.class, B.class})
public class BTest {

    @Autowired
    private B b;
}
```

If you have few dependencies you could use this way, but I didn't found solution for enabling initialization for package.

Answer (score 0):

Mock dependencies that are not in the scope of a given type of test (e.g. unit test):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BTest {
    @Mock
    private A aMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private B bService;
    
    @Test
    public void testStuff() { ... }
}
```

In the test above, I mocked A service with `@Mock` which is a dependency of B service. Then the mock is injected in `B` via `@InjectMocks`. Then, you can test methods from `B` while mocking the ones from `A`.